# how to use $.storage for multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm building a canvas where I will have multiple objects and images being moved around and I want to save them in local storage to be retrieved on a later viewing.

I think jQuery's `$.storage` plugin would be ideal, but I don't know how to save more than one object in it. The jquery api says its syntax is:

```
$.Storage.set({"name1":"value1", "name2":"value2", etc})`
```

But this is only good for one object. Would I be able to create multiple objects within the argument list? Or maybe store an array?

Comment: Which `localStorage` plugin is it? Is it [this one](http://sites.google.com/site/daveschindler/jquery-html5-storage-plugin)?

Comment: And if it is that one, I see: "Names and values should be strings. Some browsers may accept non-string values, but not all do." So you're really saving one name to one (string) value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create JSON strings and store them so when you retrieve the data you can parse them as JSON and get an object out of it. That way you can store all the information about a single element in an object.

**UPDATE**

Here is a tool that you can include to "stringify" JavaScript objects into JSON (it will add this functionality in browsers that don't have this already): https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

And you can nest objects if you want:

```
var myObj = {
        level_one : {
            level_two : {
                key : 'val'
            },
            level_two_too : {
                level_three : {
                    key : 'val'
                }
            }
        },
        level_one_too : {
            key : 'val'
        }
    },
    str = JSON.stringify(myObj);
```

The `str` variable will now hold a string like this:

```
{"level_one":{"level_two":{"key":"val"},"level_two_too":{"level_three":{"key":"val"}}},"level_one_too":{"key":"val"}}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ycxcV/

**UPDATE**

So your `$.storage()` function call would be something like this:

```
$.Storage.set({"element-one":JSON.stringify($('#element-one')), "element-two":JSON.stringify($('#element-two'))})
```

Here is an updated demo that shows creating a JSON string and parsing it back into an object: http://jsfiddle.net/ycxcV/1/
This will store the jQuery objects associated with the `#element-one` and `#element-two` DOM elements in local-storage.

Comment: @Jasper--this would be for only one object though, right? How would i use the JSON string for multiple objects?

Comment: @codeninja - It appears that you have to pass an object to the `.set()` function, which then operates on that object. What Jasper is saying is that you could possibly pass a JSON-formatted string in as a value in one of the key/value pairs, and it would save that string by that name, which you could then retrieve and convert back to a native JS object.

Comment: @JaredFarrish--do you mind providing an example of what you mean? I'm not that familiar with JSON, and i'm still a bit lost...

Comment: @codeninja Here is a demo for turning a JavaScript object into a JSON string: http://jsfiddle.net/ycxcV/ (it's quite easy)

Comment: @Jasper--this is definitely making more sense now. Once I have `set` the objects, how would i retrieve in a different session them coordinates/size intact?

Comment: @codeninja Well you would use `var json_str = $.storeage.get('key-name')` function to get the string from local-storage and then use jQuery Core's `$.parseJSON()` to parse the string into an object (that will be the same as the original object that got stringified): http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: @codeninja I updated the demo to include turning the JSON string back into an object (make sure to watch your console log): http://jsfiddle.net/ycxcV/1/

Comment: @Jasper--i dont see the `$.storage.get()` method in your code. How is are the objects retrieved from local storage without it?